# Specifying max value for google chart axis in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-visualization

I have an angular app and I am using Google charts (https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart) to show some data with the help of chart.

Currently my chart looks like following:

[image]

The horizontal axis is the number of users of my application which I am fetching from my backend. As of now, this is somehow restricted to 4, I can not find anywhere is the code where it is specified. Is there any way I can set the horizontal axis's limit to total number of users?

My code looks like following:

```
//Populate chart values
                $scope.myChartObject.data = {"cols": [
                  {id: "t", label: "Parameter", type: "string"},
                  {id: "s", label: "Number of users", type: "number"}
                  ], "rows": [
              {c: [
                {v: "Today's total logins"},
                {v: $scope.today_login_count},
              ]},

              {c: [
                {v: "Last week's total logins"},
                {v: $scope.week_login_count}
              ]},

              {c: [
                {v: "Last month's total logins"},
                {v: $scope.month_login_count},
              ]},

              {c: [
                {v: "Users who completed our trainign plan"},
                {v: 0},
              ]}
          ]};


            $scope.myChartObject.options = {
              'title': 'App usage analytics at a glance'
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.myChartObject.options = {
              'title': 'App usage analytics at a glance',
              'hAxis': {
                title: 'Total users',
                minValue: 10
              },
            };
```

solved the problem!